# JavaScript Context in HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient, javascript-engine

hi i need to Execute all the java Script on the page that i downloaded using HttpCleint Get method, which are the steps to perform the execution of the javascript containned on the page on the context of the page without loosing the connectio to the server. thx

Comment: the develop is running under java

Comment: I'll update your tags then...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) don't know if you can pass your downloaded page but it can download the page it self.

Comment: yes i have been tryng with that lib but it i need to manipulate the content of the page,, like image extraction , i dont know if you can do that with that lib

Comment: Never done that myself but if I remember correctly it returns a HtmlPage when it loads a URL which is a complete DOM tree so it should be possible.

Comment: the question is that it had to implement a JAvaScript Engine like rhino,, in the context of the page downloaded and rewrite the cookie with the new values of the executed script